# Test if a column matches given values

Tags: r, match, vectorization

I'm trying to test a column of my dataset for dynamically changing given values. The values come from a previous calculation and change all the time, such that the `ifelse` command cannot be used.

I tried it with a for-loop since it needs to be flexible but it was not working. An example of my problem is below:

```
require(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(step=c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,4,4,4,4,6,5,7,7,3,4,3,1))
data <- mutate(data, col2 = 0)
data <- mutate(data, col3 = 0)
data_check <- data.frame(step=c(3,4))    

for(j in 1:length(data_check)){
  for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    if(data$step[i] == data_check[j]){
      data <- mutate(data, Occurrence = 1)
    } else {
      data <- mutate(data, Occurrence = 0)
    }
  }
}
```

The goal is to get an additional column 'Occurrence' in the dataset, which tells if any of the given values occur or not.

Comment: Sorry my brain's tired, can you give one or two specific examples of what your output should be like? Best to describe it in words, not code. I don't get what data_check is supposed to be doing either.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I just need to compare the data with the data_check. Normally I do it with an ifelse command, but since the data_check changes all the time, I would like to have something "automated" (therefore the loop). If one of the values in data equal one of the values in data_check it should mark that in an additional column (Occcurence). I need this additional column for further calculations.

Comment: I don't get what the for-j loop is doing, you can use `%in% data_check`. I don't get what col2, col3 are doing; they're not used at all. You don't need the inner if-command, you could do `data <- mutate(data, Occurrence = (data$step[i] == data_check[j]))`. But even that would still be convoluted. Just step back completely from the code and explain in plain English exactly what output you're trying to achieve eg. *"given a series data$step of length n, and a vector data_step with s values, create an n x s matrix showing whether each entry in data$step equals the corresponding element in step"*?

Comment: So in your specific example where `data_check <- data.frame(step=c(3,4))`, exactly what output are we expecting in `data$step? data$col2? data$col3?` Just post us the exact numeric values in the output vector. Then we can infer how to compute it.

Comment: If data$col2, col3 are unused, delete them already. If they are used, tell us how they're used.

Comment: I am new to R, that is why I am asking here. And I am sorry if my English was not understandable, it is not my mother tongue! I just created these two columns to show that it is a dataset and that the loop needs to work with $ (in data$step) because sometimes I had struggled with that.

Comment: First off, each function inside the inner `for` loop changes the value of the entire `Occurrence` column. i.e. if `data$step[[i]] == data_check$step[[j]]` then `data <- mutate(data, Occurrence = 1)` sets Occurrence to 1 for the whole column, which is why your for loop isn't working, not that it is the correct approach.

Comment: Oh. You could just do `data$col2 <- data$col3 <- NA`. Doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to test if each entry in `data$step` is present in `data_check` or not, then something like:

```
data_check <- list(3,4) # so you can use the %in% operator

data$Occurrence <- data$step %in% data_check

 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

EDIT: and as Eumenedies said, you want to apply `as.numeric()` to that.

Comment: `data <- mutate(data, Occurrence = as.numeric(step %in% data_check$step))` should also work and replicate what the for loop is trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to work out how to do it in a join but I think that's probably overkill.

Comment: `%in%` is also known as the `match()` operator. And it's vectorized. It is your new friend...